# Bootstrap 3 column grid parse error in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I'm trying to create 3xN grid in my razor view.

I have

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (i == 1)
    { <div class="row"> }  // if item is first in row, open row div
      <div class="col-md-4">
// do some work here to show model data
      </div>
      @{ // if item is 3rd in row, close row div
        i++;
        if (i == 4)
        { </div>
          @i= 1;
        }
      }
}
```

but i'm getting parse error that @foreach block is not closed with } character...

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically when you have markup in code blocks that don't have ending tags in the same block you should just add `@:` to the beginning of the start tag.. Looks like you will be missing the closing `</div>` if you never reach `i = 4` so you might want to change your code up a little.

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (i == 5)
        {
            @:</div><div class="row">
            i = 1;
        }
        <div class="col-md-4">
            // do some work here to show model data
        </div>
        @{ i++; }
    }
</div>
```

Comment: @: is awesomesauce. thanks!!!!! and oct23 is my birthday double thanks =D